# Sign-in using adaptive card in bot framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I want to give it some conversation after that it should return adaptive card and then based on input data(response) from that adaptive card, it should proceed further I am getting adaptive card but without getting any response it shows the further processes, it is not taking reponse from user for that too:

Can anyone help me with this?

```
       var card = {
            'contentType': 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
            'content': {
              "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive- 
               card.json",
              "type": "AdaptiveCard",
              "version": "1.0",
              "body": [{
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "columns": [{
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 2,
                    "items": [{
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Sign-in",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "size": "medium",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
                        "isSubtle": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "size": "small"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Username",
                        "wrap": true
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "Username",
                        "placeholder": "Username"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Password",
                        "wrap": true
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "Password",
                        "placeholder": "********",
                        "style": "password"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                ]
              }],
              "actions": [{
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit",
                "data":{
                  "x":13
              }
              }]
            }
          };

          var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .addAttachment(card);
          session.send(msg);
          console.log("raw body212", card["content"]["actions"][0]["data"]);
          {
        var Username = card["content"]["actions"][0]["data"]["Username"];
        var Password = card["content"]["actions"][0]["data"]["Password"];
        if (Username = "abhishak" && (Password = "abhishak")) {
            console.log("raw body21", body);


         var purchase_payload = {
            .............................
          };

          ticket_purchase(purchase_payload, function (body) {
            console.log("raw body", body);
            session.send(
              "Your ticket has been purchased.Your available balance is " + body["data"]["availableBal"] + " and your ticket number is " + body["data"]["ticketData"]["ticketNumber"]
            );

            function createReceiptCard(session) {
              return new builder.ReceiptCard(session)
                .title(body["data"]["ticketData"]["gameName"], 'Game')
                .facts([
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["ticketNumber"], 'Ticket Number'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["playerPurchaseAmount"], 'Ticket Cost'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["saleTransId"], 'Sale Transaction Id'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["purchaseTime"], 'Purchase Time'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["gameName"], 'Game'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["drawData"][0]["drawId"], 'Draw Id'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["drawData"][0]["drawName"], 'Draw Name'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["drawData"][0]["drawDate"], 'Draw Date'),
                  builder.Fact.create(session, body["data"]["ticketData"]["drawData"][0]["drawTime"], 'Draw Time')
                ])
                .total(body["data"]["availableBal"], "Available Balance")
            }
            var card = createReceiptCard(session);
            console.log("aka2", card);
            var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(card);
            session.send(msg);

          });
        } else {
          session.send("Invalid Username/Password.");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Abhishak! Can I ask what channel you're using?

Comment: Sir, I am using Rasa Core, Rasa NLU with HTTP API and Microsoft Bot Framework with Node.js

Comment: I mean how are you communicating with your users? Facebook, Skype, directline, etc?

Comment: Also, is this a v4 bot or v3?

Comment: Currently on Skype but later on many other plateform like Facebook, directline etc.  and this is v4 bot.

Comment: Hi Abhishak, are you still having issues with this?

Comment: Yeah I am unable to take response from user.